# Unable to make rest calls to hyperledger fabric deployed using the AWS Blockchain Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I've set up a Hyperledger Fabric network using the AWS Blockchain Templates.  The network is fine and can be viewed using the Explorer. But when I try making rest calls using cURL, I don't get a response. SSHing into the ec2 instance and running the netstat command shows that port 7050 is open and listening. But my rest calls do not give the response listed [here](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#rest-api).
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hyperledger Fabric network deployed using the AWS Blockchain Template has Fabric version 1.1.0 and as such has no REST API. Instead it has the orderer operating at port 7050. Sorry for the confusion.